# Android : Is it possible to set multiple click on Image

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

#### Is it possible to add ClickListener on that particular area of Image in Android ?

[image]

Comment: There is nothing built in for this.

Comment: You will need need to handle touch events and detect the touched area.